# Get response from Moya Response

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, moya

I am using RxSwift and Moya to call request and get response.

My code:

```
NetworkManager.shared.request(api: .carrot2diamond, showLoading: false).subscribe({ (response) in
// how to handle with response
}).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```

It shows something like this:

> ["Moya_Logger: [03/01/2017 16:52:50] Request:
>   http://api.360live.vn/api_shop/carrot2diamond?appversion=1.0&auth_key=f4aeaa8f9df1fd8ef68e1f3e431cd77995d565ef66e7dff9&devid=EA51920A-5C21-41D8-A420-62AF6AAD20FD&platform=2"]
>   ["Moya_Logger: [03/01/2017 16:52:50] Request Headers: [:]"]
>   ["Moya_Logger: [03/01/2017 16:52:50] HTTP Request Method: GET"]
>   ["Moya_Logger: [03/01/2017 16:52:50] Response:  { URL:
>   http://api.360live.vn/api_shop/carrot2diamond?appversion=1.0&auth_key=f4aeaa8f9df1fd8ef68e1f3e431cd77995d565ef66e7dff9&devid=EA51920A-5C21-41D8-A420-62AF6AAD20FD&platform=2
>   } { status code: 200, headers {\n    \"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\" =
>   \"*\";\n    \"Content-Length\" = 53;\n    \"Content-Type\" =
>   \"application/json; charset=utf-8\";\n    Date = \"Tue, 03 Jan 2017
>   09:52:50 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)\";\n
>   \"X-Server\" = 360Live;\n} }"] ["{\"error\":0,\"message\":\"exchange
>   carrot value invalid\"}"]

I want to detect the error from this line:

> ["{\"error\":0,\"message\":\"exchange carrot value invalid\"}"]

When I po `response.element?.response?.description`, it just give me:

> ▿ Optional
>     - some : " { URL: http://api.360live.vn/api_shop/carrot2diamond?appversion=1.0&auth_key=f4aeaa8f9df1fd8ef68e1f3e431cd77995d565ef66e7dff9&devid=EA51920A-5C21-41D8-A420-62AF6AAD20FD&platform=2
>   } { status code: 200, headers {\n    \"Access-Control-Allow-Origin\" =
>   \"*\";\n    \"Content-Length\" = 53;\n    \"Content-Type\" =
>   \"application/json; charset=utf-8\";\n    Date = \"Tue, 03 Jan 2017
>   09:52:50 GMT\";\n    Server = \"Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)\";\n
>   \"X-Server\" = 360Live;\n} }"

Comment: The `response` you said is `Event<Response>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved this problem by adding `mapJSON()` after calling `request`.

The declaration of `mapJSON()` is

```
func mapJSON(failsOnEmptyData: Bool = default) -> Observable<Any>
```

It's description says:

```
Maps data received from the signal into a JSON object. If the conversion fails, the signal errors.
```

My code:

```
NetworkManager.shared.request(api: .carrot2diamond, showLoading: false).mapJSON().subscribe({ (response) in
   if let element = response.element, let dic = element as? [String: AnyObject], let message = dic["message"] as? String {
       print(message) // ->>>> exchange carrot value invalid
   }
}).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
```